# why Exception.getMessage() differs between postgres jdbc 8.3 and jdbc 8.4 versions?

Tags: java, postgresql, exception, jdbc

I caught the Exception from postgres through Java Excetpion, but it brings different kind of message in the postgres jdbc 8.3 and 8.4 drivers...

When I use Exception.getMessage() with 8.3 jdbc driver, it brings

> ERROR: "my pgsql raise exception"

When I use Exception.getMessage() with 8.4 jdbc driver, it brings

> ERROR: "my pgsql raise exception"
>
> Where: SQL statement "statement where the error happens"

How can I avoid the "Where:" clause without splitting the String??

This is my code:

> ```
>    try {
>       ...
>    } catch (Exception e) {
>        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
>    }
> ```

Comment: There is nothing that obliges PostGRES to keep their error messages constant between versions. It's also hard to believe that PostGRES really provides such an illiterate message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want specific subfields of the error, [use the API provided](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/util/PSQLException.html).

```
try {
   ...
} catch (org.postgresql.util.PSQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getServerErrorMessage().getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

If you want to do more complicated things than a simple catch, Apache ExceptionUtils can be handy.